# PHP read files protected by Apache

Tags: php, apache, security

I blocked a directory of my client web site due to segurity issues.
In these directory there are some pdf files, that users can read logging-into the application.
In this way when they click on the pdf to download, doesn't appear the URL of the file.

By the way an hacker could find it and read these files, so I blocked the directory.

Now I need to let my users read the pdfs.
How can I do in php?
I mean, only authenticated users can read these files.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: PHP has direct access to the file system, and can bypass any/all Apache security restrictions (except a mod_security chroot jail).

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP runs in Apache Server it 'acts' as the Server User (e.g. www-data) it will be able to access this directory, if the www-data user has the privileges to access it. Any other authorization checks have to be done in PHP by authentication and authorization workflows.

Comment: The idea is: going to www.mysite.com/docs/mypdf.pdf nobody can download the file. In apache I redirect /docs/ directory to the homepage. But a logged user, throw the application, can lists his pdf and download them, without knowing the path (www.mysite.com/docs/mypdf.pdf)

Comment: Yep that is the point. You will have a directory on the filesystem, that is accessible by Apache to provide the files. Everything else, like setting rights for Users of your Software should be done within your software. So you need to keep metadata about the files' access rights in e.g. a database.

Comment: And how can I tell to Apache that the user can download the file?

Comment: Well you could use HTTP basic authentication, but that is not at all what you really want.  Issue is how you serve the file, think about not linking to the file, rather use PHP to 'serve' the file.  So the URL is something like `/servePdf.php` and there you authenticate.  Never exposing the actual URI of the file.

Comment: That is what I do, I use a viewdoc.php file to open the pdf, but the directory containing this pdfs is now blocked for security reasons (appeared as google search result)

Comment: then you have to add privileges for the user used by the server to acces the directory and files

Comment: could you write an example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: that has to be done on filesystem level. if you use ubuntu it could be sth like `sudo chown www-data /path/to/pdf` and `sudo chmod XXX -R /path/to/pdf` where XXX has to be replaced with the rights you want the www-data user to have.